# Renaming file inside GZIP archive without extracting it

Tags: python, gzip

Is there a way, using a Python, of renaming a file, inside a `GZIP` archive, without uncompressing it?

The starting point is the following:

```
my-archive.gz
    |_file1.txt
    |_file3.txt
```

My goal (renaming the **file3.txt** as **new-file2.txt**) would be then:

```
 my-archive.gz
    |_file1.txt
    |_new-file2.txt
```

Any idea about how to achieve that?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: If there are multiple files, it is probably something else compressed with gzip. For example, a .tar.gz file.

Comment: answered at duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561749/how-to-rename-tar-gz-file-without-extracting-the-contents-and-creating-the-new

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rename .tar.gz file without extracting the contents and creating the new .tar.gz file in UBUNTU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561749/how-to-rename-tar-gz-file-without-extracting-the-contents-and-creating-the-new)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "gzip archive". gzip is a single file or single stream format.